# Docker-compose with django and postgresql could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

I built a system using docker compose with 2 container, one for django and the other one for my database postgresql. I have this error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution` when I am trying the create a django superuser

My docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "sleep 10 && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_HOST=db  # Définir DB_HOST pour correspondre au nom du service db dans docker-compose.yml

    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

My Dockerfile :

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

In the seeting.py file of my project :

```
import os
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_NAME'),
'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
'HOST': 'dbdo',
'PORT': 5432, #default port you don't need to mention in docker-compose
}
}
```

The containeurs seem to work correctly, I can see my django app page and navigate. But I am trying to create a superuser and when I do the command "python3 manage.py createsuperuser" I get the error :

```
(base) apprenant@apprenant-HP-ZBook-15-G3:~/Documents/DevIA/Projet_DevIA/Test/project_docker/projet$ python3 manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 263, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/apprenant/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/apprenant/Documents/DevIA/Projet_DevIA/Test/project_docker/projet/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/apprenant/Documents/DevIA/Projet_DevIA/Test/project_docker/projet/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 88, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 447, in execute
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 564, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 323, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 299, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 281, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 263, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apprenant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/apprenant/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

If someone can help me find the solution, it would be great, thanks a lot :)

I read it might be a problem of free space, I did "docker system prune" and a clean my disk whit bleachbit (but I only have 9,5GB left on my disk)

Comment: you run this command on cotainer shell or host shell? you must run it on container shell

Comment: I was running this command on VS code in my project directory

but thanks to your comment I tried on a linux terminal using this command fisrt : docker exec -it <container_name> bash

and it is working from there ! thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must run this command on container shell:

```
docker compose exec -it web /bin/bash
```